# App Display become darker when I login using Google or Facebook - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, facebook-login, google-signin

I try the same method for login Google or Facebook in my App
When the login is successfully, the display become darker I don't know why

[image: Before login]

[image: Login]

[image: After Login]

hmm it's weird huh?, the logic that I think maybe possible when I try to login and the pop up show up and display become darker, when login succesfully the display still intact with darker screen

[image: Pop Up]

UPDATED
I found the problem
I use this in Fragment Home progress dialog, when the api success the progress dialog will hide, when I remove progress dialog function the problem clear, is that the only solution?

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Progress...");
    progressDialog.show();
```